# Argmax indexing in pytorch with 2 tensors of equal shape

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

**Summarize the problem**

I am working with high dimensional tensors in pytorch and I need to index one tensor with the argmax values from another tensor. So I need to index tensor `y` of dim `[3,4]` with the results from the argmax of tensor `x`with dim `[3,4]`. If tensors are:

```
import torch as T
# Tensor to get argmax from
# expected argmax: [2, 0, 1]
x = T.tensor([[1, 2, 8, 3],
              [6, 3, 3, 5],
              [2, 8, 1, 7]])

# Tensor to index with argmax from preivous
# expected tensor to retrieve [2, 4, 9]
y = T.tensor([[0,  1,  2,  3],
              [4,  5,  6,  7],
              [8,  9, 10, 11]])
# argmax
x_max, x_argmax = T.max(x, dim=1)
```

I would like an operation that given the argmax indexes of `x`, or `x_argmax`, retrieves the values in tensor `y` in the same indexes `x_argmax` indexes.

**Describe what you’ve tried**

This is what I have tried:

```
# What I have tried
print(y[x_argmax])
print(y[:, x_argmax])
print(y[..., x_argmax])
print(y[x_argmax.unsqueeze(1)])
```

I have been reading a lot about numpy indexing, basic indexing, advanced indexing and combined indexing. I have been trying to use combined indexing (since I want a slice in first dimension of the tensor and the indexes values on the second one). But I have not been able to come up with a solution for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather):

```py
idx = torch.argmax(x, dim=1, keepdim=true)  # get argmax directly, w/o max
out = torch.gather(y, 1, idx)
```

Resulting with

```py
tensor([[2],
        [4],
        [9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `y[T.arange(3), x_argmax]`?

That does the job for me...

Explanation: You take dimensional information away when you invoke `T.max(x, dim=1)`, so this information needs to be restored explicitly.